# Suggestion for using Drupal Comment in PHP Application

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, comments, review

I'm developing a web Application using PHP. And there i need to use commenting system. One of my senior suggested me to use Drupal for the commenting system, i referred some websites, but i got a contradicting answers. Some of them says "integrating Drupal with any website application will not be consistent". Is that right? Or may i use Drupal comments in my PHP Application?

I know this is not a programming question, still i need to get some experts advice for this. so i post my question here.

Comment: Did you mean Drupal, Discourse or Disqus? Or why not develop your own commenting system (they're not too bad to create from scratch)

Comment: @ChrisForrence I'm asking about Drupal. Yeah I can develop of ma own. But some advised me too reuse the existing system. Is that good to use with my php web site?

Comment: I mean, using an existing library is certainly alright. It's not clear, though, if your application will be developed as a Drupal site. If so, it'd make sense to use Drupal resources. Otherwise, I'm not so sure.

Comment: @ChrisForrence But my Application only uses PHP code, i almost completed my application. So, i just asking you some guidance whether to integrate my PHP Application with Drupal Commenting System or not?

Comment: Drupal's commenting system appears to be for Drupal-only. You'd have to redevelop your application as a Drupal application. Whether or not you'd like to do that is entirely up to you! That's why I asked my first question: did you mean Drupal, or did you mean a similarly-named library like Disqus or Discourse

Comment: @ChrisForrence then, is that good to use any other library like Disqus or Discourse, for the commenting system with my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, if the rest of your project is built in Drupal, then absolutely use Drupal's comment system. If not, you're probably better off using something else.

Drupal is a flexible content management system and framework that provides way more out-of-the-box functionality than just comments. The comment system is relatively tightly coupled to Drupal's nodes and entities and isn't currently intended to be used stand alone. Using just the comment module in Drupal would entail quite a bit of work just in disabling the parts you wouldn't be using and then figuring out how to integrate with the parts you needed. You would be in uncharted territory, with little to no documentation available to help you figure out how to do all that.

If you just need a comment system, you're better off using a stand-alone comment service (such as [Disqus](https://disqus.com/) or [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/)) or using a package tailored for comments (such as [juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) or [EasyPageComments](https://github.com/Pomax/EasyPageComments)) or writing your own comment system.

Comment: which one of the commenting system you mentioned above is good to use with PHP application? and will you please explain why? Which would be easily integrated with a complete PHP application?

Comment: I've not used any of them, but EasyPageComments is mostly written in PHP, so that's probably where I'd start. As for the rest, Disqus and IntenseDebate are both commercial services, so there may be some cost associated with them. Juvia is marked as "Currently Unmaintained", so I'd probably avoid it.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for giving me this good suggestion. Will check about EasyPageComments.

Comment: You're welcome. That said, there are plenty of tradeoffs to consider, but ultimately you may be better off writing your own comment system.